# Date format with zeros

Tags: sql-server, datepart

With this:

```
, CAST(DATEPART(Yy,DATEADD(Month,1,GETDATE())) as varchar(4)) + '-' + 
CAST(DATEPART(Mm,DATEADD(Month,1,GETDATE())) as varchar(2)) + '-' +
CAST(DATEPART(Dd,DATEADD(Month,1,GETDATE())) AS varchar(2)) AS expiration_date
```

I get this: 2013-9-2

What I need is 2013-09-02

Need to have the 0 before single digit dates. What needs to be changed?

Thank you

Comment: Where is this from? MS SQL Server?

Comment: What's wrong with `CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE()),120)`? (Aside from the fact that you're treating dates as strings at all, which should generally be avoided)

Comment: That worked perfect. How to get the date one day less? Current output 2013-09-02, need 2013-09-01

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(Month,1,GETDATE()), 120)
```

If you need the day before that date, just use `DATEADD` again:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(Day, -1, DATEADD(Month,1,GETDATE())), 120)
```

Comment: How to get the date one day less? Current output 2013-09-02, need 2013-09-01